# Duplicar registro de acuerdo a la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, un favor tengo una base de datos de las ausencias, y cada registro representa un rango de ausencia del empleado así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que necesito es duplicar el mismo registro pero solo con una fecha que seria la continuación de la columna inicioPeriodo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Vas a tener que hacer un procedimiento almacenado que lo haga...

Answer (score 0):

Esto se resuelve muy fácilmente con una tabla de números ([*tally table*](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) en inglés). Las tablas de números son tablas con una sola columna con números consecutivos. Se pueden encontrar como tablas físicas, vistas o funciones. Inclusive se pueden generar al vuelo usando CTEs en cascada.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally
```

En la versión 2019 de SQL Server tenemos la función `GENERATE_SERIES()` que funciona para este propósito, pero en caso de no tenerla, podemos hacer una similar.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GeneraSeries(
    @Inicio int = 1,
    @Fin    int
    
)
RETURNS TABLE --Regresa una tabla
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- Le ayuda a identificar que no tiene objetos asociados y tendrá cero lecturas a disco
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS( --10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --100 x 100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteNumeros(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( @Fin - @Inicio + 1) --Limitamos el número de filas
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 + @Inicio AS n --Generamos numeros del 0 al N y sumamos el inicio
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n 
FROM cteNumeros;
```

Ya con esta función disponible, solo hay que unirla a la consulta en la que quieres multiplicar las filas. Agrego también los datos de prueba, para futuras preguntas debes de incluirlos así y no como imágenes.

```
DECLARE @Empleados TABLE(
    idEmpleado  varchar(6),
    CompanySnk  int,
    FarmSnk     int,
    tipoContrato    varchar(1000),
    inicioPeriodo   datetime,
    finPeriodo      datetime,
    tipoAusentismo  varchar(100),
    horasPeriodo    decimal(10,3)
);
INSERT INTO @Empleados
VALUES( '005840', 33832, 33874, 'CONTRATO A TÉRMINO', '20120119', '20120121', 'Incapacidad IGE', 24)

SELECT e.idEmpleado,
    e.CompanySnk,
    e.FarmSnk,
    e.tipoContrato,
    DATEADD( DD, s.n, e.InicioPeriodo) AS FechaAusentismo,
    e.tipoAusentismo,
    e.horasPeriodo / (d.Dias + 1) AS horas
FROM @Empleados e
CROSS APPLY( SELECT DATEDIFF( DD, e.InicioPEriodo, e.finPeriodo) AS Dias) d
CROSS APPLY dbo.GeneraSeries( 0, d.Dias) s;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Luis Cazares, pero tengo un inconveniente que hasta hace un momento me di de cuenta y es que estoy utilizando Azure Synapse y la función GENERATE_SERIES y los CTE recursivos no son compatibles.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno muchas gracias a la ayuda de Luis Cazares me ayudo mucho, pero en Azure Synapse no soporta CTE recursivos ni esta la función GENERATE_SERIES. Pero hay una solución muy sencilla para el tema y es tener una dimensión de calendario en el datawarehouse y así logre solucionar lo que necesitaba.

```
select 
e.idEmpleado,
e.CompanySnk,
e.FarmSnk,
e.tipoContrato,
c.date as FechaAusentismo,
e.horasPeriodo / (d.Dias + 1) AS horas,
e.tipoAusentismo
from Staging.CTAS_FactEmployeesAbsenteeism_Delta e
LEFT JOIN BusinessCore.Calendars C ON C.[Date] between e.InicioPeriodo and e.finPeriodo
CROSS APPLY( SELECT DATEDIFF( DD, e.InicioPEriodo, e.finPeriodo) AS Dias) d
```